# How do you set the #include path for Sparx Enterprise Architect reverse engineering?

Tags: c++, enterprise-architect

It only looks in the directory I select from "Import Source Directory..."

I looked at Local Paths, but I don't think that's it.

Answer (score 0):

EA only reverse-engineers actual C++ source code, not preprocessor code. In other words, it doesn't resolve `#include` or other preprocessor directives. (It has some minimal handling of `#define`:d macros, but that's it.)

It might work if you import the `#include`:d files first. The other alternative is to run the source through the preprocessor before importing it.